# What's the fastest way to read a file from start to finish?

Tags: c, linux, file

I ran my code through a profiler and saw most of the time (60%) is spent reading files. It only takes a few milliseconds to run but I was wondering if I can make it any faster. My code has a list of 20 files (from 1k to 1M). It opens one, reads the entire file into ram, process it (sequential, reads everything once), then repeats open/read/process/close for the rest of the files reusing the same buffer

I was wondering if there's a way to make anything faster? I tried using posix_fadvise with POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL and POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED, using the file offset len as `0, 0` and `0, st_size`. It didn't seem to make a difference. I haven't yet written code to open all the files before reading. Would that make a difference? Should I be using posix_fadvise on all of them? Should I be using POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL or POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED?

Comment: File IO is a common bottleneck. It sounds that there is not much you can do.

Comment: If it's only 20M, put the files on a ramdisk.  Or use SSD.

Comment: If you don't show any code, it is very difficult to see how your code can be optimized.  Do you want us to guess?  Or you prefer us to give you the best solution in all possible cases without knowing your environment, your architecture, your compiler, or your interest in getting your question answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fadvise` only really helps if:

1. It's issued well before you begin reading, or
2. You're reading the file piecemeal (ideally with some processing gaps between the reads).

If you're just slurping the whole file into RAM up front immediately after opening it, there's not much to be optimized; the file has to be read from beginning to end, and you haven't given the OS enough warning to cache it. Things to consider:

1. Opening and `fadvise`ing file n+1 just *before* you begin reading from file n (so the OS is caching the next file in while you're processing the current file)
2. Using `mmap`+`madvise(WILLNEED)` to avoid the need to copy the file from kernel to user buffers all at once before you can begin processing; if the processing of the file is expensive enough, the subsequent pages may be read in by the time you've finished processing the early pages in the file.

Given these are small files, I'd just stick with `WILLNEED`; `SEQUENTIAL` enlarges the read-ahead buffer, but you're going to read the whole file anyway (possibly in bulk, where `SEQUENTIAL` won't help much) so you may as well cache the whole thing in as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept in a few days when I can measure this better and confirm it works

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this code, extracted from the first edition of *"The C programming language"* its quite difficult to superate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```